# Action is not being called in XMLHttpRequest

Tags: image, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to upload a file by XMLHttpRequest. After uploading I am trying to show preview of the image by calling an action as a source of the image.

Here is the code sample:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.file = file;
xhr.onreadystatechange = function (e) {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) { // here I am updating the image source
        document.getElementById('imagePreview').src = '@Url.Action("GetTPImaegeByName","Techpack",new { area="OMS" })';
    }
};

xhr.open('post', 'someurl', false);
var fd = new FormData;
fd.append('photo', file);
xhr.send(fd);
```

Here @Url.Action("GetTPImaegeByName","Techpack",new { area="OMS" }) returns an image file.
For the first time the source of the image is updating and shown correctly. But if I try again to change the file the it doesn't work. Looks like the action to update the image source is not being called. Need help to solve this problem.

Comment: And how are you calling this javascript when the image changes?

Comment: I've taken a file input. I am calling this script onchange of that 'file input'. Before calling this script I've also checked for the file type to confirm that the selected file is an image.